# clGetPlatformID error when running OpenCL program.

Tags: opencl

I've been trying to make OpenCL work in my laptop. I followed [this](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2015-03-16/how-to-install-opencl-on-windows/) link for that. I have an NVIDIA GT525M video card and Windows 8.1. 
The steps I followed were:

Installing the up-to-date NVIDIA drivers.

Installing Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Adding the paths for the linker and the compiler.

and then I tried to run the following code as given in that page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>

int main(void)
{
    cl_int err;
    cl_uint* numPlatforms=NULL;

    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL,numPlatforms);
    if (CL_SUCCESS == err)
        printf("\nDetected OpenCL platforms: %d", numPlatforms);
    else
        printf("\nError calling clGetPlatformIDs. Error code: %d", err);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code builds successfully but the result I get is:

```
Error calling clGetPlatformIDs. Error code: -30
```

I get zero as the number of platforms. 
I've been looking all over the internet for a solution but couldn't find one. Please help.

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva sorry for asking dumb questions here. But the documentation wasn't very clear there. (or I am too dumb to understand it) thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
cl_uint* numPlatforms=NULL;
err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL,numPlatforms);
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, NULL);
```

Which doesn't make sense. As per the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html):

> Returns CL_SUCCESS if the function is executed successfully. Otherwise it returns CL_INVALID_VALUE if num_entries is equal to zero and platforms is not NULL, or if both num_platforms and platforms are NULL.

`CL_INVALID_VALUE` is the -30 you are getting, for the reasons stated above.

What you really want is the following:

```
cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
```